# Possible to bind an event to each handle of a range slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

Range slider

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true, min: 0, max: 420, values: [0, 420], slide: slideTime, change: toSpin
    });
```

and text fields

```
$('#min').val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
$('#max').val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
```

and I would like to call a function when the value of each field changes, like

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
```

but since the mouse is never in the field it won't work.  Maybe local storage is the answer, but before getting into it I thought I would see if I can just bind the slider handles instead.

I can use #slider-range like this:

```
var $leftslider = $("#slider-range");  
      $leftslider.bind("mouseup", sliderHandler);
function sliderHandler() {
```

but I guess I would need to bind mouseups to each handle, left and right separately, to call a different function for each. So, after the slider changes #min, the left handle mouseup would call a function that uses the value of #min.

Variations on this theme

```
$(#slider-range).children('.ui-slider-handle').first().offset();
```

seem not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you would like to do it with events you could do it this way:

```
$('#min').val(ui.values[ 0 ]).trigger("input");
```

And then you could listen this way:

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
```

You could also think over using a custom event name to make clear that it is not a regular event, but one you triggered yourself.

Comment: It works but it makes the second input field trigger its function when the first one is changed, which is the problem I have run into with every approach.  `$('#min').val(myminval).trigger("inky");` and `$("#min").on('inky', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was "offset" at the end there.  The correct way:

```
var $thang = $("#slider-range").children('.ui-slider-handle').first() //removed offset() here;
        $thang.bind("mousedown", thangHandler);
```

You heard me:  thangHandler.